# getting an undefined error when trying to findOne using sequelize with mysql and node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

To the best of my knowledge I've setup the promise on this call correctly and `res.send();` does seem to be being called, however there is an error being thrown and all it's telling me is that the error is undefined. This isn't much help to me obviously.

the line that seems to be causing an issue is:

```
 db.user.findOne({ where: {username: testUser} })
                        .then((username) => {
                            res.send({'created user':username.id});
                        })
```

I'm trying to create a user and then once that is finished look up the id of the newly created user and create a session for them. The user is definitely being created, however I've noticed when inspecting on chrome that the variable passed into username AFTER fineOne is empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const util = require('util');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const session = require('express-session');


const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

//require models
const db = require("../models/index");
var input = req.body;
    try{ //validation
                req.check('firstName').isLength({min:1, max:100});
                req.check('lastName').isLength({min:1, max:100});
                req.check('email').isEmail();
                req.check('username').isLength({min:1, max:15}).isAlphanumeric();
                req.check('password').isLength({min:8, max:100});

            // check for errors in validation obj!
            var errors = req.validationErrors();
            if (errors) {
                res.send('There have been validation errors: ' + util.inspect(errors), 400);
                return;
            }

            var testName = input.firstName;
            var testName2 = input.lastName;
            var testEmail = input.email;
            var testUser = input.username;

            //hash password
            const saltRounds = 10;
            bcrypt.hash(input.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
                var testPass = hash;
                debugger;
                //insert user and newly hashed password into db
                db.user.create({
                    first_name:testName,
                    last_name:testName2,
                    email:testEmail,
                    username:testUser,
                    hashed_password:testPass})
                    .then(
                    // search for just added user
                    db.user.findOne({ where: {'username': testUser} })
                        .then((username) => {
                            res.send({'created user':username.id});
                        })
                        .catch(err=>console.log('err',err))
                    )
                    .catch(err=>console.log('error:', err));
            });

        }catch(error){
            //console.log('validation error:',error);
    }
```

Comment: First Check following tasks of debugging error-> 
    1) check username stored in db or not.
    2) find which position of catch err occured
    3) check response username contains values or not using console.log

Comment: turns out the find all request needed to be wrapped in an anonymous function. :)